# How can I create xxx.tar.bz2 file of a directory with compression using command?

Tags: bash, command

I tried :

`tar -czvf /tmp/tmppu4ryjsz/yyy/xxx.tar.bz2 -C /tmp/tmppu4ryjsz/xxx .`

this creates a xxx.tar.bz2 file but when its extracted, extracted file will be `tmp > tmppu4ryjsz > yyy`
I need it to contain only `yyy`

Comment: You're not even using Python here. I think you may want to ask this on SuperUser, but even if this is the right site for it, it's not the right tag.

Comment: @abarnert: It's possible to edit the tags you know :)

Comment: @l'L'l Sure, but I think the question should just be migrated or closed.

Comment: @abarnert: I agree 100% with you.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the full path when listing the files

`-C /tmp` is to change the dir

`hsperfdata_mdm` without the full path

```
[  0][s: / ]$ tar -cf /home/sakis/asd.tar -C /tmp hsperfdata_mdm
[  0][s: / ]$ tar -tvf /home/sakis/asd.tar
drwxr-xr-x mdm/mdm           0 2018-04-04 11:29 hsperfdata_mdm/
[  0][s: / ]$
```

Comment: It's just yyy in your case. This is an example (a dir in /tmp/ in my case), you should use your directory names.